# Raw socket not capturing DHCP packets on correct interface but Wireshark is

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp, wireshark

I'm following this C application example of a raw socket sniffer:

https://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/

Except I binded the socket to my interface after creating the socket:

```
const std::string& iff = "wlp3s0";

int r = setsockopt(sock_raw, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, iff.c_str(), iff.length());
if (r == -1)
{
    std::abort();
}
```

I then leave the application running:

```
sudo ./the_app
```

I open Wireshark and listen to wlp3s0 wireless interface. I removed the wired Ethernet interface from the capture.

I then run `sudo dhclient -r` and `sudo dhclient` to stop/start DHCP and Wireshark detects 4 or 5 DHCP packets, as expected:

[image]

However, the C raw socket sniffer shows absolutely no UDP packets received.

If I then open a web browser, it starts to show TCP packets (Wireshark reported the DHCP packets were UDP).

What's happening? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04

Minimal example:

```
#include<stdio.h>   //For standard things
#include<stdlib.h>  //malloc
#include<string.h>  //memset
#include<netinet/ip_icmp.h> //Provides declarations for icmp header
#include<netinet/udp.h> //Provides declarations for udp header
#include<netinet/tcp.h> //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include<netinet/ip.h>  //Provides declarations for ip header
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* , int);

int tcp=0,udp=0,icmp=0,others=0,igmp=0,total=0,i,j;
struct sockaddr_in source,dest;

int main()
{    
    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536); //Its Big!
    
    printf("Starting...\n");
    int sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(sock_raw < 0)
    {
        std::abort();
    }

    int r = setsockopt(sock_raw, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "wlp3s0", strlen("wlp3s0"));
    
    if (r == -1)
    {
        std::abort();
    }
   
    while(1)
    {
        int data_size = recv(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0);
        
        if(data_size <0 )
        {
            std::abort();
        }

        ProcessPacket(buffer , data_size);
    }
    
    ::close(sock_raw);
    return 0;
}

void ProcessPacket(unsigned char* buffer, int size)
{
    //Get the IP Header part of this packet
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)buffer;
    ++total;
    switch (iph->protocol) //Check the Protocol and do accordingly...
    {
        case 1:  //ICMP Protocol
            ++icmp;
            //print_icmp_packet(buffer, size);
            break;
        
        case 2:  //IGMP Protocol
            ++igmp;
            break;
        
        case 6:  //TCP Protocol
            ++tcp;
            //print_tcp_packet(buffer , size);
            break;
        
        case 17: //UDP Protocol
            ++udp;
            //print_udp_packet(buffer , size);
            break;
        
        default: //Some Other Protocol like ARP etc.
            ++others;
            break;
    }

    printf("TCP : %d   UDP : %d   ICMP : %d   IGMP : %d   Others : %d   Total : %d\r",tcp,udp,icmp,igmp,others,total);
}
```

Comment: Your code running as root?

Comment: @selbie yes, I'll add that to the Q

Comment: Can you show an [mcve]. That is, all your socket code including `socket`, `bind` and `recvfrom` calls?

Comment: @selbie added. You will need to change the interface name in `setsockopt()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, of course you are not receiving UDP packets. You are explicitly only asking for TCP packets with `IPPROTO_TCP`:

```c
int sock_raw = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

After all, the very guide you are following tells you this:

> 1. The above sniffer picks up only TCP packets, because of the declaration:
>
>    ```c
>    sock_raw = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW , IPPROTO_TCP);
>    ```

---

Now you may think of using `IPPROTO_RAW`, but that is only possible for *sending*, as [`man 7 raw`](https://manned.org/raw.7) explains:

> A protocol of `IPPROTO_RAW` implies enabled `IP_HDRINCL` and is able to send any IP protocol that is specified in the passed header. **Receiving of all IP protocols via `IPPROTO_RAW` is not possible using raw sockets**.

So you cannot receive multiple protocols with an `AF_INET` socket. You will need an `AF_PACKET` socket and slightly more complex code. See [`man 7 packet`](https://manned.org/packet.7) for more info.

Note that in this case you will have to bind using [`bind(2)`](https://manned.org/bind.2) and `struct sockaddr_ll`, you cannot use `setsockopt(SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...)` with `AF_PACKET` sockets, as [`man 7 socket`](https://manned.org/socket.7) states:

> **`SO_BINDTODEVICE`**
>
> [...] Note that this works only for some socket types, particularly `AF_INET` sockets.  It is not  supported  for  packet  sockets (use normal `bind(2)` there).

Comment: Yes, you have to `bind` in a slightly different way, using the _index_ to the interface. An example in my answer: [AF_PACKET and Ethernet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54057044/5382650)

Comment: @CraigEstey that code seems overcomplicated, you can get the index with `if_nametoindex("name")`.

Comment: When I wrote the original code, I wasn't aware of the convenience function `if_nametoindex`. But, if you look at the code for `if_nametoindex`, it does exactly what my code does (e.g. using `SIOCGIFINDEX` with `struct ifreq`) to get the index for the interface. But, `if_nametoindex` does a `socket` call and then a `close` on it. In my code, it does a `socket` call, uses it to get the interface index, and then passes that file descriptor to the `bind`, so fewer open/close calls on the sockets.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks. I was seeing icmp packets so didn't think it was restricted to tcp only.

Comment: @CraigEstey Still not getting UDP. To confirm, using your function the socket creation should look like this: `int netsock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));` ?

Comment: @intrigued_66 The code does use `SOCK_RAW`. The `SOCK_UDP` (never used because of the `#if`) was holdover from when the function was in development [and I was experimenting--7 years ago sigh ;-)]